# Framework7: Split view degrading to tab bar? (combined examples)

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

Completely new to Framework7 and not yet fully grasping the layout. Was trying to combine two examples provided, namely the split view degrading to panel: [framework7.io/examples/split-view-panel/](http://framework7.io/examples/split-view-panel/) with the tab bar layout [framework7.io/examples/tab-bar/](http://framework7.io/examples/split-view-panel/) so that iPads and the like would get a split panel view and iPhones get the tab bar. (i.e. show/hide the tab bar using the same css query that shows/hides the sidebar)

I started from the split panel view, added the custom css from the tab bar app and added .tabs .toolbar-through to the .views div. Added .tab .active to the .view-main div. And copied and pasted the toolbar code:

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels">
  <div class="toolbar-inner">
    <a href="#view-1" class="tab-link active"> <i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-1"></i><span class="tabbar-label">Information</span></a><a href="#view-2" class="tab-link"><i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-2"></i><span class="tabbar-label">Inbox</span></a>
    <a href="#view-3" class="tab-link"> <i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-3"><span class="badge bg-red">4</span></i><span class="tabbar-label">Upload</span></a>
    <a href="#view-4" class="tab-link"> <i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-4"></i><span class="tabbar-label">Photos</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That adds the toolbar to the DOM but it's not visible. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6295yqs/

Mucking around in the dev tools I can't really understand from the generated output why it's not showing, it's not an issue with z-index or general visibility... Any pointers on how to get this working would be deeply appreciated

(Note, haven't added the css to hide and display the tab-bar to the fiddle though that should be easy enough)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the tab-bar code to right below the

```
  <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
```

Also added a class - .m-hide to the tab-bar divs.

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .xs-show {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t6295yqs/2/